# Finding a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $I := [1,2)$. Find a sequence $(a_n) \subset I$ such that, for any convergent subsequence $(b_n)$ of $(a_n)$, we have: $\lim b_n \notin I$.

I want to say $a = 2-\frac1n$.

Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take any sequence which converges to $2$. In your example all elements of $~~(2 - \frac{1}{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}~~$ lie in $I$ but its limit $2$ doesn't belong to $I$. Since the sequence is convergent, any of its subsequences converges too and has the same limit (which as seen above is not in $I$). So your example is correct.